# Apply CSS rules only if set classes are present, and not others

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need the rules to apply to this element:

```
<div class="a b"/>
```

And not this one:

```
<div class="a b c"/>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the :not() selector, but I'm interested if there's a way to just limit rules to a set number of classes without the additional :not() clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. It will apply only on where the class name matches.

```
div[class*="ab"]{

 /* Write your style that  you want to apply  */

}
```

Comment: I take it won't work in the case of class="b a", but it'll do. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use title tag within div and apply the style to title. For example `<div class="ab" title="ab" > </div> <div class="abc" > </div>`  write css in this format `div[title~=ab]{ /*Your style */ }` Now this will apply the style to class where the title would be ab